# How to limit memory use when using a stream

Tags: stream, racket

I'm working with a data set that is too big to fit into memory and therefore would like to use a stream to process the data.  However, I'm finding that the stream isn't limiting the amount of memory used as I expected.  The sample code illustrates the problem and will run out of memory if the memory limit is set to 128mb.  I know I could up the memory limit, but with the sort of big data set that I want to use this won't be an option.  How should I keep the memory use down?

```lisp
#lang racket

(struct prospects (src pos num max-num)
  #:methods gen:stream
  [(define (stream-empty? stream)
     (equal? (prospects-num stream) (prospects-max-num stream)))
   ;
   (define (stream-first stream)
     (list-ref (prospects-src stream) (prospects-pos stream)))
   ;
   (define (stream-rest stream)
     (let ([next-pos (add1 (prospects-pos stream))]
           [src (prospects-src stream)]
           [next-num (add1 (prospects-num stream))]
           [max-num (prospects-max-num stream)])
       (if (< next-pos (length src))
           (prospects src next-pos next-num max-num)
           (prospects src 0 next-num max-num))))])

(define (make-prospects src num)
  (prospects src 0 0 num))

(define (calc-stats prospects)
  (let ([just-a (stream-filter
                 (λ (p) (equal? "a" (vector-ref p 0)))
                 prospects)]
        [just-b (stream-filter
                 (λ (p) (equal? "b" (vector-ref p 0)))
                 prospects)])
    ;
    (let ([num-a (stream-length just-a)]
          [num-b (stream-length just-b)]
          [sum-ref1-a (for/sum ([p (in-stream just-a)])
                        (vector-ref p 1))]
          [sum-ref1-b (for/sum ([p (in-stream just-b)])
                        (vector-ref p 1))])
      ;
      #|
          ; Have also tried with stream-fold instead of for/sum as below:
          [sum-ref1-a (stream-fold
                       (λ (acc p) (+ acc (vector-ref p 1)))
                       0 just-a)]
          [sum-ref1-b (stream-fold
                       (λ (acc p) (+ acc (vector-ref p 1)))
                       0 just-b)])
      |#
      ;      
      (list num-a num-b sum-ref1-a sum-ref1-b))))

;================================
;           Main
;================================
(define num-prospects 800000)

(define raw-prospects (list #("a" 2 2 5 4 5 6 2 4 2 45 6 2 4 5 6 3 4 5 2)
                            #("b" 1 3 5 2 4 3 2 4 5 34 3 4 5 3 2 4 5 6 3)))

(calc-stats (make-prospects raw-prospects num-prospects))
```

*Note:  This program was created just to demonstrate the problem; the real stream would access a database to bring in the data.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem in your code was that you were trying to make multiple passes through the stream. (Each call to `stream-length` is one pass, and each of your calls to `for/sum` (or `stream-fold`, for that matter) is another pass.) This means that you had to materialise the whole stream without allowing the earlier stream elements to be garbage-collected.

Here's a modification of your code to make only one pass. Note that I made `num-prospects` to be 8,000,000 in my version, since even the multi-pass version didn't run out of memory on my system with only 800,000:

```lisp
#lang racket
(require srfi/41)

(define (make-prospects src num)
  (stream-take num (apply stream-constant src)))

(define (calc-stats prospects)
  (define default (const '(0 . 0)))
  (define ht (for/fold ([ht #hash()])
                       ([p (in-stream prospects)])
               (hash-update ht (vector-ref p 0)
                            (λ (v)
                              (cons (add1 (car v))
                                    (+ (cdr v) (vector-ref p 1))))
                            default)))
  (define stats-a (hash-ref ht "a" default))
  (define stats-b (hash-ref ht "b" default))
  (list (car stats-a) (car stats-b) (cdr stats-a) (cdr stats-b)))

;================================
;           Main
;================================
(define num-prospects 8000000)

(define raw-prospects '(#("a" 2 2 5 4 5 6 2 4 2 45 6 2 4 5 6 3 4 5 2)
                        #("b" 1 3 5 2 4 3 2 4 5 34 3 4 5 3 2 4 5 6 3)))

(calc-stats (make-prospects raw-prospects num-prospects))
```

I should clarify that the use of `srfi/41` is simply to enable writing a more-efficient version of `make-prospects` (though, the reference implementation of `stream-constant` isn't very efficient, but still more efficient than what your `prospects` stream generator did); `calc-stats` doesn't use it.

Comment: This works, however I'm struggling to understand why the GC can't clear the elements generated by `stream-length` and `for/sum`, in particular if I replaced the `for/sum` lines with two more `stream-length` ones I get the same problem, but I would have thought the GC could easily see that the generated elements could be collected.

Comment: Remember that streams memoise all the elements that are materialised, so that each element is generated at most once. This is why if you materialised the whole stream, such as by calling `stream-length`, all the elements would be memoised and they would not be collected until the stream nodes holding them are also collected.

Answer (score 3):

I upvoted Chris' excellent answer and suggest you pick it to mark as accepted.

However, what would use the least memory for a data set that doesn't fit into RAM? Probably something like the following pseudo code:

```
(require db)
(define dbc <open a db connection>)
(define just-a (query-value dbc "SELECT Count(*) FROM t WHERE n = $1" "a"))
(define just-b (query-value dbc "SELECT Count(*) FROM t WHERE n = $1" "b"))
```

Why this is a somewhat smartypants answer:

- Ostensibly you asked about using Racket streams to handle things that don't fit in memory.
- If you need more complex aggregations than count (or sum/min/max), you'll need to write more complex SQL queries, and probably want to make them stored procedures on the server.

Why it isn't necessarily smartypants:

- You did mention your real use case involved a database. ;)
- A speciality of a DB server and SQL is large data sets that don't fit in memory. Taking advantage of the server often will beat something DB-ish re-implemented in a general-purpose language (as well as probably being friendlier to other uses/users of the same DB server).

Comment: This would be the ideal from the information I gave, hence +1, however I need the users to be able to write the queries themselves and need to also allow for CSV input.

Answer (score 1):

You are running out of memory because you are hanging onto the head of the stream while traversing it. The GC can't collect anything because since you have a pointer to the head, every element of the stream is still reachable.

To demonstrate, with this stream:

```
(define strm (make-prospects raw-prospects num-prospects))
```

this blows up:

```
(define just-a (stream-filter (λ (p) (equal? "a" (vector-ref p 0))) strm))
(stream-length just-a)
```

while this is fine:

```
(stream-length (stream-filter (λ (p) (equal? "a" (vector-ref p 0))) strm))
```